<the> age distribution of a population
I know the definite article isn't necessary when using "age distribution of a population". But when I searched for "age distribution of the population", all quotes use "the". Is using "the" preferable than not using it? Why is that? I know it's correct either with or without "the" because "distribution" is uncountable.

I simply have used Census data on the age distribution of the
population for the years shown to compute a crude weighted average. (Forbes)


In that sentence the is essential. Note that distribution is not uncountable. The report summarised three different age distributions: male, female, and total population.

@PeterKirkpatrick, thanks. if "distribution" is not uncountable, why does this quote from Forbes not use "the"? However, the report did pull a few interesting data points about income distribution across Metropolitan Statistical Areas.

The quote from Forbes in your question does use "the." Are you talking about a different quote?

@AndyBonner, I am talking about the quote in my comment. You said in another answer that age distinction is countable only in statistics. I disagree with Peter because of the new quote and your previously answer.

I'm still confused: You said here, "why does this quote from Forbes not use "the"?," but it does.

You seem to think that if a noun is countable, it must have "the" attached to it. Is that what you think? If you do, you're wrong. There are many different principles and variations when using the definite article. (I'm a guitar player. Sometimes I play guitar, and sometimes I play the guitar. Work that one out!)

"age distribution" (without article) is a topic.  "the age distribution" (with article) is an attribute.

Today we're going to be discussing age distribution of target customer populations and its relevance to the choice of background music in TV ads.
Could you describe the age distribution of the target customer population for your little self-propelled vacuum cleaner, and explain to the audience why you chose Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata as the music for your TV ads?


Thanks for the answer. Is this difference important? Although I understand your examples, I probably won't be able to tell whether to use "the" or not when writing.

@newbieforever Do you understand the difference between a topic and an attribute clearly enough that you could tell in your own sentences whether you were speaking of the one or the other?  Attribute takes precedence.

I understand what a topic is but don't understand what an attribute is. I don't know how to apply this definition to age distribution-a quality or characteristic that someone or something has. Can you explain it in the context of age distribution？

In the phrase "the strength of oak", "strength" is an attribute of "oak", one of the wood's characteristics. So we say "the strength of oak". But if we want to talk about the using strong materials to make durable furniture,  we're referring to "strength" abstractly as a topic in its own right, not as an attribute of a particular material. So we say "Strength is an important consideration when choosing materials to make durable furniture."  And so "age distribution" is like "strength" and "the age distribution (of a particular population)" is like "the strength (of a particular wood)".

Another example to reinforce @TimR's excellent comments. I mentioned guitar playing in another comment. I could say, Guitar playing requires lifelong study to achieve excellence (topic). I could also say, The guitar playing of Eric Clapton really inspires me (and shows my age!) (attribute)
